# Какой знак препинания нужно поставить перед словом если?

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания нужно поставить перед словом если? Я поставила двоеточие. В описании товарных позиций указано: есть ли самовывоз.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Пока не вижу ни слова "если", ни текста самого вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь нужна запятая. Двоеточие было бы возможно в случае перечисления указываемого или в случае однозначного раскрытия того, что именно указано. Например:

```
... указано (следующее): a) есть ли самовывоз, б) требуется ли предварительный заказ и в) какова минимальная партия товара.

... указано: возможен самовывоз.
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Единственно возможным знаком препинания в данном случае является запятая, если я уловил смысл предложения.

*В описании товарных позиций указано, есть ли самовывоз.* Указано (что?), есть ли самовывоз. Это придаточное изъяснительное.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

> Какой знак препинания нужно поставить перед словом если? Я поставила
>   двоеточие.

Лучше поставить **запятую.**

Comment: Большое спасибо.